# Active Directory - Bulk Company Update

Tags: active-directory, user-management, dsquery

I was wondering if there is a way to update the 'Company' field for a large group of users within Active Directory? I would like to match all users with a company ending in a certain string.

It would take way too long to change this for each user individually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
dsquery user -name * -limit 0 | dsmod user -company "%COMPANY%"
```

Adjust the `dsquery` to target specific users as required.

**Edit:**
To match on a specific [sub-]string

```
dsquery * -filter "&((objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(company=*OLDCOMPANY))" -limit 0 | dsmod user -company "%NEWCOMPANY%"
```

Adjust the `*OLDCOMPANY` regex to suit your needs.

Comment: +1 Dead simple, and should work great!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - playing with it now. Can this be modified to only change users where the company ends with a particular string?

Comment: +1 I like dead simple

Comment: @JT.WK: Updating my answer...

Comment: +1 Very nice solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! You saved me hours or repetition! Cheers!

Comment: +1 Win.  I was about to write the same thing using Find, DSQuery, DSGet, and DSMod - but yours is a much more elegant solution

Answer (score -1):

Write a powershell script to change it for all users where the company = the old company name to the new company name.

Comment: Well yeah, you probably could do something in powershell.  But that in itself isn't a helpful answer - what are the powershell commands for searching and modifying users?

Comment: true but was pointing in a good direction thanks for the -1

Comment: A cryptic reference to an an even more cryptic scripting language, with no real information about solving the problem is not a good answer - ever. I'll credit it to inexperience rather than downvote it.

Comment: *"...answering and driving"*  -- As in *while* driving a motor vehicle?  Please don't do that, it's incredibly dangerous to yourself and others on the road.